# How to Cleanup Full Disk on Elasticsearch Node while Elasticsearch is not running

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, disk

I have Elasticsearch 7.4 with 1 master and 5 data nodes (Amazon ec2 instances). I have cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled setting = false
Now one of the disk in a node became full and elasticsearch stopped due to disk full error.

```
ElasticsearchException[failed to load metadata]; nested: IOException[No space left on device];

/dev/nvme1n1p1  493G  468G     0 100% /disk1
```

After this, cluster shows only 4 data nodes, 9 shards are still unallocated and search requests are being denied, while other nodes still have enough space left on their disks.

I want to make some space by deleting old data through POST API but that won't work in this case.

Now my question is, how can I cleanup the disk on this node while it only contains elasticsearch data and is not available in the cluster.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elasticsearch save the indices files in DATA folder with UUID. you can find your DATA folder path in elasticsearch.yml.

also you can find indices UUID with `GET /_cat/indices?v`

consider that I assume you have time based indices and can delete a indices. if you want to delete some document of offline indices, that is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... First it's one big index with 52 shards (not time based indices). Second, I already know UUID, inside that folder, there are 5 different folders which are shards... Is there any way to move / delete data from a node that doesn't start elasticsearch, or a way to start elasticsearch in deleteOnly mode and create space by deleting old data through API

Comment: if you have 52 shards, move one or two shard to free node. maybe you face with dangling indices problem but it can be configure.

Comment: you can not delete shard or docs when elasticsearch is not fully up

Comment: if you have replica you can delete shard in this node

Comment: did change watermark in elasticsearch? how do you reach 100% of disc?

Comment: yes, unfortunately had this setting disabled already and I did not know about it until it happened.
    cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled setting = false
Also replica is not configured, and how can I move shards in an offline node?